# Problems while using nnetar on R

Tags: r

Im very new on R and I had a problem while trying to use nnetar, this is my code:

```
consum<- data$consumo
consum = ts(data,
             start = 1971,
             frequency = 1)
Model = nnetar(consum,
               size = 64,
               repeats = 1000)
forecastM = forecast(Model, h = 15)
plot(forecastM)
forecastM
```

The main problem is when I saw the plot the forecast data starts very with a very low value compared with the last real data

does someone knows how to fix this problem? or I need to make some extra process with my data?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's unclear exactly what the problem is here.